# Como tratar esse NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Não estou entendo o motivo de receber um `NullReferenceException`, nessa linda do código:

```
pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;
```

O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Segue código inteiro

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ClienteViewModel viewmodel)
        {
           // verifica se o Model CLIENTEVIEWMODEL está válido 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Pessoa p;
                //verifica o tipo de pessoa para add no entity
                if (viewmodel.TipoPessoa.Equals(Models.Enum.TipoPessoa.Juridica))
                {
                    //cria a pessoa juridica
                    p = new PessoaJuridica();
                    // atribui a pessoa da viewmodel para o objeto pessoa
                    p = viewmodel.Pessoa;
                    var pessoaJuridica = p as PessoaJuridica;

                    pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;

                    db.PessoaJuridica.Add(pessoaJuridica);
                }
```

**EDIT**

mensagem de erro completa:

> Detalhes da Exceção: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Classe **PessoaJuridica**:

```
public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
{
    [DisplayName("Inscrição Estadual")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public String InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
   {

        public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

        public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa { get; set; }

        public PessoaJuridicaViewModels PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: você poderia postar a mensagem de erro completa?

Comment: Teu `viewmodel.PessoaJuridica` tá nulo, parça. Tem que ver isso aí.

Comment: Eu depurei o valor de `viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual`´ e está vindo o valor.

Comment: em qual linha da o erro?

Comment: @Dorathoto nessa `pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;`

Comment: ou o `viewmodel`, ou `PessoaJuridica` estão nulos, seria bom postar mais código aí, até porque se vc está fazendo `async` as coisas complicam um pouco mais

Answer (score 1):

`viewmodel.PessoaJuridica` está vazio, então não é possível vc acessar o subnível dele..pode dar um breack point e verificar.
faça algo do tipo `var teste = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica;` e veja

e no final ficará assim

```
if(viewmodel.PessoaJuridica != null)
{ 
  pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se viewmodel.PessoaJuridica está nulo.

```
if(viewmodel.PessoaJuridica != null)
{
    pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variável `pessoaJuridica` não foi instanciada

**Instancie:**

```
var pessoaJuridica = new PessoaJuridica();
```

**Caso queira atribuir:**

```
var pessoaJuridica = p;
```

**Instancie os atributos no construtor da sua classe:**

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public ClienteViewModel() 
    {
        Pessoa = new Pessoa();
        TipoPessoa = new TipoPessoa();
        PessoaJuridica = new PessoaJuridicaViewModels();
    }

    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    public PessoaJuridicaViewModels PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok mas quando escrevi esse trecho: `p = new PessoaJuridica();
                    // atribui a pessoa da viewmodel para o objeto pessoa
                    p = viewmodel.Pessoa;
                    var pessoaJuridica = p as PessoaJuridica;`Não estaria instanciando P e add na PessoaJuridica?

Comment: Se você disse que a sua viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual não esta nula, então a variável pessoaJuridica  não foi instanciado.

Comment: Certo obrigado, mas como atribuo então os dados da `viewModel.Pessoa` para a pessoa juridica?

Comment: Como esta sua classe PessoaJuridica? poderia colocar o codigo?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi bastaria você fazer:  p = new PessoaJuridica();
p = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica;

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: modifiquei minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a NullReferenceException é levantada na seguinte linha:

```
pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;
```

Isto quer dizer que o operador de indireção `.` está sendo chamado num objeto nulo. Como os objetos que recebem o operador `.` são `pessoaJuridica`, `viewmodel` e `viewmodel.PessoaJuridica`, o culpado é **necessariamente** um dos três.

Vamos ver se traçamos de onde vem cada um:

```
public async Task<ActionResult>
Create(ClienteViewModel viewmodel) {
    // verifica se o Model CLIENTEVIEWMODEL está válido 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        Pessoa p;
        //verifica o tipo de pessoa para add no entity
        if (viewmodel.TipoPessoa.Equals(Models.Enum.TipoPessoa.Juridica)) {
            //cria a pessoa juridica
            p = new PessoaJuridica();
            // atribui a pessoa da viewmodel para o objeto pessoa
            p = viewmodel.Pessoa;
            var pessoaJuridica = p as PessoaJuridica;

            pessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual = viewmodel.PessoaJuridica.InscricaoEstadual;

            db.PessoaJuridica.Add(pessoaJuridica);
        }
        /* O método continua... */
    }
}
```

Comecemos por `pessoaJuridica`: ela é uma reinterpretação da variável `p` (de tipo `Pessoa`) como `PessoaJuridica`. Esta, por sua vez, é instanciada com um objeto `Pessoa` vazio na linha 8, e este objeto é imediatamente descartado em favor do membro `Pessoa` da variável `viewmodel`, que é um argumento da função. Então, se `viewmodel` vier com uma `Pessoa` não instanciada, `p` passa a ser `null` na linha 10 e levanta a exceção na linha 13.

Examinemos, então, `viewmodel`: este é o argumento da função, mas como já teve outros membros acessados (iniciando com `viewmodel.TipoPessoa` na linha 6), então ele não pode ser nulo, visto que não é atribuído no método.

Finalmente, `viewmodel.PessoaJuridica`, que é um membro de `viewmodel`. Este também não é atribuído no método, então a única possibilidade é ele chegar nulo na função.

Por conclusão, a `viewmodel` que você está recebendo como parâmetro deve ter *ou* a propriedade `Pessoa` *ou* a propriedade `PessoaJuridica` nulas (ou as duas). Eu conferiria então o código que instancia esse `viewmodel` antes de ele chegar no método...